# how to get the OUT variable value from a stored procedure in oracle from php which is in a package

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in my oracle db in a package. Say my package name is myPackage and procedure name is myProcedure, in the procedure there are two parameters, one varchar2 IN parameter and one varchar2 OUT parameter. I used the following code

```
<?php
  $conn = oci_connect("username", "password", "123.456.7.890/XXX");
  if (!$conn) {
  $m = oci_error();
  trigger_error(htmlentities($m['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
  }
  $p1 = 'MUKUND';
  $p2 = 'g';
  $stid = oci_parse($conn, "begin xx_sample.sayHello(:p1, :p2); end;"
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p1', $p1);
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p2', $p2);

  oci_execute($stid);


  print "$p2\n";



  oci_free_statement($stid);
  oci_close($conn);
```

and in xx_sample.sayHello  see the spec and body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package APPS.xx_smpl
    AS
     procedure sayHello (name1 IN VARCHAR2, greeting OUT VARCHAR2) ;
     END;
  /
```

body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package body APPS.xx_smpl AS
PROCEDURE sayHello (name1 IN VARCHAR2, greeting OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
greeting := 'Hello ' || name1;
END;
END;
/
```

And i ran it in sqldeveloper, i got the result but when i ran it in php via the above code i am not getting any output.

One more thing to mention is that, what ever tutorials in went through, `i didnt find any tutorial where the procedure is called via package.`

So i created another procedure which i found in this site

http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.examples.php

i created the following procedure, this time no package,

```
<?php

 $conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
 if (!$conn) {
 $e = oci_error();
 trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
 }

 $p1 = 8;

  $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'begin myproc(:p1, :p2); end;');
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p1', $p1);
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p2', $p2, 40);

  oci_execute($stid);

  print "$p2\n";   // prints 16

  oci_free_statement($stid);
  oci_close($conn);
```

corresponding procedure is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc(p1 IN NUMBER, p2 OUT NUMBER) AS
BEGIN
p2 := p1 * 2;
END;
```

but this time i am getting the output when i run this php file!!!

So someone please tell me what am i doing wrong? please help me to get the output

Comment: Shouldn't it be `begin APPS.xx_smpl.sayHello(:p1, :p2); end;`

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar I edited the question, i tried that also